# How to represent small numbers in postgresql?

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to represent numbers from `0-23` in a `postgresql` table, and also index them.

What's the best datatype for this type of data?

```
postgres=smallint
java=short
```

Or could I do better? There is also a `TINYINT` datatype in postgres, but how would I represent eg "23" in java then?

Comment: Java has `byte` for numbers between -128 and 127. But besides that, why bother? Are you running under heavy memory constraints?

Comment: Yes I'm running heavy memory, approx 500 mio rows.

Comment: If you have 500 million rows, then a regular index on 24 values is unlikely to be helpful.  You might see some gains with a clustered index, but that slows down inserts.

Comment: Postgres doesn't have `TINYINT`, the smallest numeric datatype is the 16-bit `SMALLINT`.

Comment: So you have a lot of data, but do you _really_ have a problem with memory? 500m rows probably means your database is massive anyways so whether those numbers require a few GB of hd more shouldn't matter. And in case of Java, you'll probably not want to load all those rows at once but use a paging approach.

Comment: @membersound You can potentially do "better", but you haven't explained your problem. You're just talking about datatypes and making mistakes in that too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `"char"` type (note the double quotes, they are important) in PostgreSQL which will occupy only one byte and use `byte` in Java:

```
CREATE TABLE chartest (
   id integer primary key,
   c "char");

INSERT INTO chartest (id, c) VALUES (1, 42::"char");
```

You'll have to cast the expression to `integer` when you query the value so that you can use the `getByte(int)` method:

```
java.sql.Statement st = conn.createStatement();
java.sql.ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT c::integer FROM chartest WHERE id = 1");
rs.next();
System.out.println(rs.getByte(1));
```

**Note:** Attributes are always aligned according to the [`typalign`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-type.html) property of the data type.
For example, if you add a new column of type `integer` immediately after column `c` from the example above, there will be three bytes wasted and empty between these columns.
So you have to be careful with the physical layout if you want to save space.

You might save some space on the database that way, but I don't know if it is worth the effort. If I were you, I'd experiment to see if it pays off.